# Connection to Node server timing out - port is open

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating an app that must connect to my windows computer's node.js server...

Using MongoDB, Express, and Node.js, I am attempting to access the server using port 3000. My iphone (or any other device) can connect to the node server/DB fine when on the same network as my machine running the server.

I am timing out when trying to access the server on a different network (Mobile or a different wifi).

I tried binding my express app to '0.0.0.0', as well as the currently set dhcp IP address given to my machine running the sever.

Netstat is telling me the port is open.

[netstat -an](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ9V7.png)

Here is my index.js code:
1. I set the port at the top of document
2. I create the server using the port 3000 and host "0.0.0.0" at the very bottom.

```js
var http = require('http'), express = require('express'), path = require('path');

MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver,
FileDriver = require('./fileDriver').FileDriver;

var app = express(); // create Express.js object
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());

var mongoHost = 'localHost'; // CHANGE THESE WHEN ACCESSING A SERVER ON A DIFFERENT MACHINE
var mongoPort = 27017;
var fileDriver;
var collectionDriver;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort)); 
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) { 
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1); 
  }
  var db = mongoClient.db("MyDatabase");
  fileDriver = new FileDriver(db);
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db); 
});



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
});

// For saving session rail/prize pictures
app.post('/files', function(req,res) {fileDriver.handleUploadRequest(req,res);});
app.get('/files/:id', function(req, res) {fileDriver.handleGet(req,res);});
// For saving Account Profile Pictures
app.post('/accountPictures', function(req,res) {fileDriver.handleUploadRequestAccount(req,res);});
app.get('/accountPictures/:id', function(req, res) {fileDriver.handleGetAccount(req,res);});

// req (request) - The request contains information from the browser:
//                  HTTP agent, information passed in and more
// res (response) -  The response is what we will send back to the user
app.get('/:collection', function(req, res) { 
   var params = req.params; 
   collectionDriver.findAll(req.params.collection, function(error, objs) { 
       if (error) { res.send(400, error); } 
       else { 
           if (req.accepts('html')) { 
               res.render('data',{objects: objs, collection: req.params.collection}); 
              } else {
           res.set('Content-Type','application/json'); 
                  res.send(200, objs); 
              }
         }
    });
});
 
app.get('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Here was made")
  var params = req.params;
  var entity = params.entity;
  var collection = params.collection;
   if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.get(collection, entity, function(error, objs) { 
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); } 
       });
   } else {
      res.send(400, {error: 'bad url', url: req.url});
   }
});

// Add data
app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) { 
    var object = req.body;
    var collection = req.params.collection;
    collectionDriver.save(collection, object, function(err,docs) {
          if (err) { res.send(400, err); } 
          else { 
           res.send(201, docs); 
          } 
     });
});

// Update data by _id
app.put('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) { 
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity; // Name of object retrieved from collection (DB)
    var collection = params.collection; // Table Name (Accounts, JamLocations, etc.)
    if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.update(collection, req.body, entity, function(error, objs) { 
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); } 
       });
   } else {
       var error = { "message" : "Cannot PUT a whole collection" };
       res.send(400, error);
   }
});

// Delete data by _id
app.delete('/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) { 
    var params = req.params;
    var entity = params.entity;
    var collection = params.collection;
    if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.delete(collection, entity, function(error, objs) { 
          if (error) { res.send(400, error); }
          else { res.send(200, objs); } //200 b/c includes the original doc
       });
   } else {
       var error = { "message" : "Cannot DELETE a whole collection" };
       res.send(400, error);
   }
});




// Catch all for app.verb, creates a 404 error
app.use(function (req,res) { 
    res.render('404', {url:req.url});
});

// CREATES SERVER
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), "0.0.0.0", function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('host') + " - " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Server connects to Mongo fine.

Here I created an inbound rule to open up port 3000...
[inbound rule - port 3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evXRd.png)

I did my best to exhaust all other solutions on stackoverflow and across the web...please point me to any helpful readings if they exist!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the IP address your server is on a public IP address that is available from outside your private network.  If not, that's how you access something from the outside.  You will either need a server at a hosting center with a public IP address or you will need to do port forwarding of the public IP address from your firewall/router to the private IP of the server.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response...I have set my machine to a static IP address, and set port forwarding on port 3000 to my machine via my routers wireless setting page. Still no luck accessing the server via another network. I have tested to see if my router's port 3000 is open using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/. The status returned that the port is currently open.

Comment: Are you port forwarding 3000 from your public IP address to port 3000 on your private static IP address?  It sounds like you probably just didn't do something correctly with the port forwarding.

Comment: Yes, according to Verizon wireless setting page, my machine at the correct IP address, will have any TCP/UDP connection entered through port 3000, directed to port 3000 on my machine (which my node server is currently listening for).

Comment: I don't know why you have the "0.0.0.0" in the `.listen()`.  You can just remove that entirely.  If you list no ip address in the `.listen()` it will bind to the IP address of the computer which you already said was a private static IP address.  Other than that, you're going to have to do some network sleuthing to figure out why your port forwarding isn't working.

Comment: Removing the IP address from listen did not resolve the issue. I will have to do some sleuthing. Thank you for the help.

Comment: 1. It is not a Node server, you keep referring to the express server as node server or is there something different that you use to make it a node server?
2. If you need to test, just install ngrok (npm install ngrok -g), it will expose your localhost to the outside world. ngrok will provide its own port though.